# Can we optimize the performance of `std::map::find` by providing a hint?

Tags: c++, optimization, stdmap, std

The method `std::map::emplace_hint` allows us to optimize the performance of `std::map::emplace` by providing a "hint" iterator that we expect to be very close to the location where the item will be emplaced.  This is probably most useful when you are emplacing many items in quick succession.

I'm writing some code where I expect to need to call `find` to get a large number of values in quick succession.  I expect the keys to be near one another but not necessarily adjacent.  There isn't a `std::map::find_hint`, but is there a way to do something similar using existing methods in the standard library?  Basically, I just want to speed up `find` by providing an iterator that is near the key.

This question probably applies more broadly to most of the sorted C++ standard library containers, of course, but today I'm specifically interested in `std::map`.

Comment: Consider using `unordered_map`, its `find` has average `O(1)` complexity ( [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) ), while `map` which uses tree underneath has `find` with `O(log(N))` ( [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) )

Comment: If you know next element is nearby, you could just keep the iterator from first `find` call and increment it yourself? Increment in loop if it's not always the next iterator. This should be faster if in general you increment less than `log(n)` times before you reach next interesting element, but slower otherwise.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes, this makes sense.  I may need to iterate either forward or backward, but it's easy to tell the right direction because the container is sorted.  Thanks!

Comment: Seconding the suggestion to switch to `unordered_map`. The performance difference is often astonishing. If you need sorted access for some other operations, it can even make sense to keep a `map` and an `unordered_map` together (potentially with the `unordered_map` containing iterators of the `map`), just for the better lookup speed

Answer (score 0):

No, we can't. Here is the complete [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) manual.

You can use `std::find_if()` algorithm if you are pretty sure the next key to find is reachable in less than `log_2(map.size())` iterator next steps.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
  std::map<int, int> m{{1, 1}, {2, 2}};

  auto it = m.find(1);
  if (it != m.end())
    std::cout << it->second << " ";

  int k = 2;  // next key to find
  it = std::find_if(it, m.end(),
    [k](const auto& v) { return v.first == k; });
  if (it != m.end())
    std::cout << it->second << "\n";
}

// Output: 1 2
```

Comment: Yes, I've looked at the manual, but was looking for other ideas.  Will think about using `std::find` and get back to you.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any overload of `std::find` that does what I want directly.  In particular I could try to search forward a certain number of steps and then backwards a certain number of steps, but this is probably easier to do manually with an iterator as Yksisarvinen suggested rather than using `std::find`.